# Azure DevOps: Both pipelines triggered when pushing to either branch

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I have created two branches for my project: main branch and develop branch. I am using Azure Devops for testing & deploying my application. I have two pipelines: one for the main branch and one for the develop branch. I want to make that the main branch would only trigger it's pipeline (excluing develop branch) and develop branch would also only trigger it's branch (excluding main branch).

Until now I tried this solution:
*azure-pipelines.yml* file in develop branch.

```
# Frontend build file

trigger:
- develop
```

*azure-pipelines.yml* file in main branch:

```
# Frontend build file

trigger:
- main
```

However, it does not work, because if I push some commits into one of the two branches, both pipelines are being triggered. What could be the issue and how could I solve it?